# How to access, in windows host, to the web interface of graylog running on a virtual ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, portforwarding, nat, graylog

I am having problems with this:
I installed graylog in ubuntu running on virtualbox as the documentation said (installing the required elasticsearch 2x and mongodb). The web interface is available at localhost:9000 by default and I can access to it after starting graylog in the virtual machine, but, and here comes my problem, I cannot access the interface in the windows host.

I am using NAT network configurations with port forwarding. Here you have a picture with the port forwarding configurations with the graylog port highlighted (the other are from other attempts):
[Port-forwarding configurations in virtualbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ieHeK.jpg)

I have test the port forwarding with xampp, I installed it in the virtual ubuntu and then configured the port forwarding as in the image (port 2223). With xampp running in the virtual machine I went to 10.46.1.24:2223 in windows and it worked.
I have tried the other type of network configurations (bridged, host-only) and it did not worked.
I tried to use the virtual appliance provided in the graylog download page too, but it did not worked.

I do not know if I am missing some configiration or something and I read again the graylog documentation to see is I was missing something but I cannot solve this and that is why I am here asking for help.

Please tell me if you know how to configure this or if you deduced that I failed in some step.

Comment: There's a dedicated community forum for Graylog at https://community.graylog.org/ in case you want to ask your Graylog-related questions there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problems, here goes what I did:

I changed (and uncommented) in th /etc/graylog/server/server.conf the variables:

- web_listen_uri to have this: IP_virtualmachine:9000/
- rest_listen_uri with: IP_vortualmachine:12900/
- rest_transport_uri: IP_windowshost:12900

Then I forward ports in virtual box NAT configurations to the same ports (9000 and 12900) in windows.

The change in rest_transport_uri is because when I enter the web interface with ip:9000, the interface try to access to the rest api (by default the defined rest_listen_uri), and as the rest_listen_uri is defined in the IP of the virtual machine, in the host it will failed, and that is why I typed my windows host ip in the rest_transport_uri. This causes the web interface to stop working in the virtual machine but it will work in th windows host.

The rest_listen_uri and the web_listen_uri are specified in differents ports because it is needed in the port forwarding (because it is not possible to forward the rest api working in ip:9000/api/.